# libvlc_media_player_stop 30secondes to return

Tags: vlc, freeze, libvlc

I'm using libvlc to retrieve raw frame from any media (rtsp, mjpeg, mp4, avi...) by using smem callbacks and everything is playing fine.

But my problem is that when i call libvlc_media_player_stop or libvlc_media_player_release it just freeze my program during 30 secondes.

I do a lot of search and try many workarounds :

Make a new thread to call the stop : doesn't solve my problem because if i want to play anew the media, the mediaplayer still hang in the main thread.

Call stop from the main thread not on the mouse event : stuck 30 secondes too.

I try different version from 2.1.3 to lastest git 3.0.0 and the problem remain the same, so how do you call this stop ?

Initialisation :

```
char smem_options[1000];
sprintf(smem_options
, "#transcode{vcodec=RV24}:smem{"
"video-prerender-callback=%lld,"
"video-postrender-callback=%lld,"
"video-data=%lld},"
, (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPrerender
, (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPostrender
, (long long int)(void*)this);

const char * const vlc_args[] = {
"-I", "dummy",      
"--verbose=0",
"--clock-jitter=0",
"--no-audio",
"--sout", smem_options // Stream to memory
};
mpLibVlc = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
```

Start :

```
mpMedia = libvlc_media_new_path(mpLibVlc, mMediaPath.c_str());
mpMediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(mpMedia);
libvlc_media_player_play(mpMediaPlayer);
```

Stop :

```
libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mpMediaPlayer, NULL);
libvlc_media_release(mpMedia);
libvlc_media_player_stop(mpMediaPlayer);
libvlc_media_player_release(mpMediaPlayer);
```

I found a lot of different issue with vlc, but that's the only library wich handle easyly all theses media.

So how can i call this stop without any hang ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `libvlc_media_player_stop` before `libvlc_media_release`?

Comment: Yes, i tried libvlc_media_player_stop only and libvlc_media_player_release only without stop too, and it always took 30 seconds.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Finally, it was my source media wich was broken (a mistranscoded flv to mp4 video file), be careful to use from_media for locale file, and from_location for ip camera by example. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Maypeur can you please provide full answer? I've got same thing and it's really annoying. Bad thing is i must save flv stream from IP camera to mp4 video file.

Answer (score 0):

@serg.v.gusev my post is old, but what i remember is :
You have to respect :
- Use libvlc_media_player_new_from_media to load local files.
- Use libvlc_media_player_new_from_location to connect to IP camera.

Anyway, in my case my original video was broken, and this is what was hanging the call to stop during theses 30 secs, the same code works with well encoded video files.

PS : i moved to ffmpeg, for both reading and recording video media. It is a little bit more complicated, but since vlc is based on ffmpeg, you have more control, possibility and update...

Comment: I can't found libvlc_media_player_new_from_location function, probably it was deprecated and removed (i work with 3.0.0-git version). But i already use libvlc_media_new_location to create libvlc_media instance. I think it's same thing. My video stream is definitely correct, so this way seems not works for me, especially given that my process locked permanently, not for just 30 seconds. Thanks for your answer anyway!